# What is the software used in this image(semiconductor simulation)?

Tags: theory, simulation

[image: Properties of semiconductors]

If I interpret this correctly, this means there is some nice software to simulate various properties of semiconductors. Does anyone know what it is or alternatively what packages do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess its PN Junction Lab: http://nanohub.org/tools/pntoy

You can also find some other tools in the same site, in the "See also" column on the right.